# Clearing CR CL and spaces in PHP string

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I was having issues when trying to use the string and when i copied it into notepad++ and viewed all characters tab it showed the following attached symbols. My knowledge is that they are line breaks and spaces. Issue is, i cant seem to get them removed from my string?

Explanation:

I have a function which uses shell_exec to grab information from a stored DB.

```
$output = trim(shell_exec("'".$command."' 2>&1")); //Trimmed version
return $output;
```

I have a credit system but when they load the page it calls the function to obtain credits depending on the user etc.

```
$Credits = Sqlite('select "Credits" from TBL WHERE User = "bla" limit 1');
```

Thing is, the credit comes back with a `�` beside it. So if i have `9.50` stored, i received `�9.50`. When looking into this, i noticed the above characters included in the string?

My PHP attempts:

```
$Credits = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $Credits); //Clear all spaces
//$Credits = str_replace(' ', '', $Credits); //Clear spaces <-- dont work either
$Credits = str_replace('\r\n', '', $Credits); //Clear all new lines
echo $Credits; //Still returns the new line etc
```

[image: string issue]

Comment: Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `$Credits = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $Credits);` should do the job. Well, if there are Unicode chars, you need `'/\s/u'`, but that does not seem to be the case here. Also, why not try [**`trim()`**](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php)?

Comment: Why you want to remove those chars?

Comment: btw. you shoud use `"\r\n"` instead of `'\r\n'` - escape sequences only working in strings with `"`

Comment: I updated answer with a bit of a better explanation! :)

Comment: Try to identify the source of the faulty characters and fix it there. Your SQlite database seems to be a likely culprit.

Comment: I was thinking that also but i manually updated the Credits to something like `9.00` and i still receive them. Very strange, will keep checking and see where these chars are coming from! Thanks.

Comment: you updated the file with notepad++? maybe you stored the file as unicode and notepad++ added the BOM header

Comment: It looks like an encoding problem. Although you may try and just use `preg_match('~\d+(?:\.\d+)?~', $s, $match)` and then use `$match[0]`, it might be a better idea to fix the encoding problem and just use `trim()`.

Comment: Your problem isn't related and can't be solved with regex or replacements. You have to find the reason of this leading byte. Actually what you can do to start your investigations is to display the hex code of the byte using: `echo dechex(ord($Credits[0]));`, then you have to find its origin.

Answer (score 0):

$Credits is just a variable and will not change the context of your file. So give this a try:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('source.txt');
echo '<pre>'; // to display any new line from linebreak
echo $text;

echo '<br>====<br>';

$text = preg_replace('/\r\n/','a',$text); // a is just an indicator of original linebreak which you can use '' empty instead

echo $text // display text after linebreak is replaced from variable $text
file_put_contents('source2.txt', $text); // save this to file with linebreaks removed
// or replace content of source.txt
?>
```